# Show that $\lim_{x→0}f(x)$ does exist and that it is equal to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

> Let $f :\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a function such that $\lim_{x\to0}
> \frac{f(x)}{x} = 7$.  Show that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ does exist and that it is equal to $0$.

I consider the case where $f(x) = 7x$ which satisfies this, but I have no idea how to prove it for a general $f(x)$.

Comment: Hint: use the product rule for limits together with a known limit (can you figure out which one?).

Comment: @AlannRosas The known limit that sticks out to me is the limit as x approaches 0 of 1/x. But that limit doesn't exist so I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: We want to use the product rule for limits together with $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)/x =7$, so try rewriting $f(x)$ as a product of $f(x)/x$ and some other function. There's one obvious function we could use for this; if you can find it, you'll immediately see how to deduce that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$.

Comment: @AlannRosas I got it! I was overthinking this. Thank you so much! (We know $lim_{x→0}x = 0$ )

Comment: Well done! I'm glad I could help :)